# How to change UserCreationForm error messages in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to change error messages in UserCreationForm. I want to change password field error messages but i don't know how. I tried this:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "my message",
    }
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

and it works, but i can't figure out how to change other messages like "password is too similar to the username", "password is too short", "password is too common" and "password is entirely numeric".
I tried adding to the error_messages 'min_length' key but this doesn't work

Comment: try searching Django source code on Github.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi, yes, there is code 'password_too_short' in password_validation.py, i tried adding this to error_messages but surprisingly, it did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy `django.contrib.auth.password_validation` to your project and create the same validators with your custom messages.

`users/password_validation.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.core.exceptions import (
    FieldDoesNotExist, ValidationError,
)

from django.utils.translation import gettext as _, ngettext


class MinimumLengthValidator(password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator):

    def __init__(self, min_length=8):
        self.min_length = min_length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if len(password) < self.min_length:
            raise ValidationError(_(f"Пароль слишком короткий. Он должен содержать не менее {self.min_length} символов."))

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(f"Ваш пароль должен содержать не менее {self.min_length} символов.")
```

And don't forget to point them out in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'users.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's a good idea, but for some reasons people say that this is a bad practice and they recommend not to do that. Plus I don't know if i will be able to edit django source code when i deploy website on hosting

Comment: I'm not telling you to override Django's source code. I have slightly updated the answer.

Comment: Uh, as we can translate errors through LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru' in settings.py, I think it would be much better to alter translations the similar way you had done it in your answer. Can you please hint me how to do it?

Comment: By default, the language code for Russian is `ru` and it already has the translations. 
Since my answer already answers your question, where is it unclear to you?